# Publishing stuck on "waiting for publish" then resumed automatically after 30 min

Tags: publishing, web8.5

We are using SDL Web 8.5 and recently we have faced an issue with publishing, it got stuck on `waiting for publish` then resumed automatically after 30 minutes. We have checked the Event Viewer and publishing log file, but could not find any errors. 
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Hi Abdul. Was this a one off or does it happen consistently? Is there anything else in the Publishing Queue at the same time? Are you sure that the Publisher Service was running properly at the time?

Comment: Hi @JonathanWilliams this happened only one time after looking at the  publisher logs we have found database connection close error just before the issue occurred so i assume it could be the reason

Comment: In that case, please add your comment also as an answer (if possible, include some more details like the log fragment) and accept it so the question becomes "closed".

Answer (score 3):

"waiting for publish" is state which doesn't mean that item is stuck. It means that item is waiting for other transactions to finish before it can start. So please check the publishing queue for all users to see if someone else sent some items to publish before you, so these transactions are processed. They can even be with higher priority than yours, so they are processed first. If item gets for long time in "deploying", "committing deployment"or "throttled" states, then you should check what is happening with publishing.